# Convergence to uniform of a finite subsets of free subgroup in $SO(3)$.

Tags: probability, lie-groups, ergodic-theory, haar-measure

One can pose this question in more generality (for dense free subgroups in semisimple Lie groups), but anyway:

It is known to some that there are elements $x,y \in SO(3)$, which generate a dense, free subgroup. Let $F_n$ be the set of words of length $\leq n$. Let $\mu_n$ denote the probability measure that is uniform on $F_n$.

Question: Does $\mu_n$ converge to the Haar measure? If so, how fast?

Comment: Are you referring to words of length $\leq n$ over $\{x,y\}$?  Also, does convergence mean *weak* convergence?

Comment: @Blackbird yes to both.

Comment: @Blackbird Are there other reasonable interpretations for the convergence of measure?

Comment: Weak convergence is probably the most natural.  I was just trying to understand your question.

Comment: I was thinking of imitating the proof of the unique ergodicity of irrational rotations, but since the group is not amenable, we cannot use the pointwise ergodic theorem...

Comment: @Blackbird I understand, thanks. What unique ergodicity are you talking about? Compact groups are amenable, I thought.